# Signed data is empty for Android in-app billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm implementing in-app billing for my Android application using [AndroidBillingLibrary](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary/.)

I've uploaded the apk to Google play and published the in-app item.
Then I've installed on my device the same apk as I uploaded to Google Play.
When I try to buy in-app Android Market sends empty string as signed data to purchaseStateChanged listener.
Any thoughts about this?